# when we create an object ,do creation of object and the execution of constructor happens at the same time?

Tags: java, constructor

When we create an object, do creation of object and the execution of constructor happens at the same time or first object is created then constructor execution take place?

Its written in the Herbert Schildt: "Once defined ,the constructor is automatically called immediately after the object is created ,before the ***new*** operator completes". My queue is that if new operator has not finished with it's memory allocation then how can be constructor be called before new gets completed as it's written constructor is called only after object is created.

Answer (score 3):

[Section 12.5 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) gives the details. The bare bones of it is:

- Memory space is allocated (with all fields having the default value for the relevant type, e.g. `null` or 0)
- The specified class's constructor is called, which will immediately chain to either another constructor in the same class or a superconstructor
- Eventually the chain reaches `java.lang.Object`
- In each constructor chain coming back down, instance variables are initialized based on their field initializers, if any (and only if we didn't chain to another constructor in the same class), then the constructor body code executed. That then returns to the calling constructor, etc.

The JLS goes into more detail, of course, including cases where there isn't enough memory or a constructor body throws an exception.

The timing of each bit of the constructor is important though:

- Chain to this/super constructor
- (Implicit) Assign initial values to fields if the chain was to a superclass constructor
- Constructor body

It's important to understand that if a superconstructor invokes an overridden method which reveals the value of a field, it will *not* have gone through the field initializer yet. So you can see the default value of the field rather than the value you'd expect to from the initializer. For example:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    private String name = "fred";

    @Override public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

If the `Foo` constructor calls `toString()`, that will `null` rather than `"fred"`.

(If `name` is `final`, then it's treated as a constant in `toString()` and other things happen, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Should the last point happen after the first? It contradicts the second one as is!

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: It doesn't but I'll give more details.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Basically, the JVM knows just by the class exactly how much memory it'll need for it _and_ all of its superclasses. It allocates all that memory, and then starts going through the constructor. (Typically, each superclass will have a block of that overall memory, but that's not specified in the JLS.)

Comment: The bit about `final` fields is interesting, because the JLS seems to contradict itself. On the one hand, the assignment to the variable should happen after the `Foo` constructor. On the other hand, JLS 15.2 states that "Some expressions have a value that can be determined at compile time. These are constant expressions (§15.28)." I think an interpretation of the JLS _could_ be that the value of the variable `Bar.name` is only assigned in the `Bar` constructor, but that doesn't matter, because any call site is just going to use the constant value and not even dereference the variable.

Comment: @yshavit: No, in this case `name` is non-final and non-constant, so it doesn't count as a constant expression. If it were `private static final String name` then yes, call sites would just use the value.

Comment: @JonSkeet In the code snippet you posted, I don't see the weird "assigned before constructor" behavior -- when Foo's constructor calls `toString()`, that returns `null`. So that's not an illustration of the situation you describe ("where ... the field is `final`"). If `name` were `final` (but not `static`), then it _would_ count as a constant expression, and you'd see the assigned-before-constructor behavior.

Comment: @yshavit: No, it's not an example of that - because it's not a `final` field. It's an example of "if a superconstructor invokes an overridden method which reveals the value of a field, it will not normally have gone through the field initializer yet". I still don't think the assigned-before-constructor behaviour is correct though; the expression `name` is *not* a constant expression, and I can't see anything in the JLS to suggest that the assignment happens at a different time.

Comment: @yshavit: Indeed, with `name` as a `final` field, if you look at the `javac` output you'll see that the assignment to `name` still only happens *after* the superconstructor call in the bytecode - it's the JIT that's optimizing here.

Comment: In the code snippet you have, when I write a `Foo` whose constructor does `System.out.println(toString())`, I see "null". I only see the assignment-before-constructor with `final String name`. And while you're right that javap shows the constructor assigning `name`, _if_ you make `name` `final`, take a look at the code for `toString` -- you'll see it loads the constant `"fred"`. With `final String name = "fred"`, the constructor assigns `name = "fred"`, but the call site (`toString`) doesn't care, because it loads the constant `"fred"` directly, without `name`. It's not the JIT, it's javac.

Comment: @yshavit: Good catch. Fetching the value of the field by reflection instead gets null. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator creates a new object by performing a few operations in sequence: it allocates memory for the object as needed (this operation might trigger other operations in the JVM), it executes the code defined in the constructor being called and finally, it returns to the caller with a reference to the newly created object. It's worth noting that the constructor call happens after all the variables are default initialized in the current class and that this same sequence happens from the topmost class in the hierarchy down to the current class (so `Object()` is executed first etc.).

So technically the constructor executes on the newly created object, i.e., the memory space allocated for it, it could never execute on memory that hasn't been allocated or is being allocated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new`, memory is allocated on the heap for the object, including it's variables which are initialized to default values. If values are supplied as constructor parameters, those values are used.

Once the constructor is finished with initialization, the variable to which it is assigned is created on the stack, with address of the object in the heap as its value.

I suggest you watch [this Stanford lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8nNdNZ40EQ) where this is explained in just enough details so that anyone can understand it.